# Can we remove the bulletproof vest on the character (GTA V - Online)?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I don't know if the purpose that we always see the vest is to show other players that you have armor on but it kinda ruins the fact that you can clothes your character with those ugly vest. Is there a way to hide the bulletproof vest in online mode ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does work in all games apart from racing, just hold select > inventory >body armor

That's what it says [here](http://gtaforums.com/topic/610860-how-to-take-off-armor-vest/).

Comment: Interesting, will have a look to see if it's working. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome. Please if it works don't forget to click on the 'check' mark. Thanks.